# Is there an automatic way to add group read permissions to “nohup.out” when “nohup” is run?

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, bash-scripting

I run my Java code from bash script using a command like this:

```
exec nohup "$JAVACMD" "${JVM_OPTS[@]}" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" com.myClass "$@" &
```

Which creates the output file `nohup.out` and this file has permissions like this:

```
-rw------- 1  24308657 Mar 24 12:52 nohup.out
```

I want the group to have read permission as well, not only the user that ran the command.

How do I do this?

Comment: What are your default permissions/what is the umask? Do all created files get this permission? (E.g. test with `touch foo`).

Comment: This answer will also solve the permission case, assuming the `umask` is set to `022` (usually this is the default): https://stackoverflow.com/a/4549515/1519522 -- though the out file name must be set, either to `nohup.out`, or any other name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a permissions change in your command by using the “and” operator (`&&`) like this:

```
exec nohup "$JAVACMD" "${JVM_OPTS[@]}" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" com.myClass "$@" && chmod g+r nohup.out &
```

Answer (score 3):

Create the `nohup.out` file *before* you run `nohup`. If necessary, give it the correct permissions when you create it.

```
touch nohup.out && nohup seq 1
```

Which would then create the file with your default permissions before `nohup` is actually run:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 rici rici 6 Mar 25 14:57 nohup.out
```

`nohup` would then append it’s output to that `nohup.out` file.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the permissions the normal way?

```
chmod g+r nohup.out
```